# Ruler and Compass construction in CGAL

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I am trying to make basic constructions like "get intersection of a line and circle", "connect two points", "create a circle" with CGAL. However, the choice of kernel seems to be a problem. When I use exact 2D circular kernel, I get `Circular_arc_point_2` from intersections, and then I can't use this data type to create lines, circles; and converting to `Point_2` seems to introduce error and then stores the approximate value as an exact number. Additionally this problem seems to be independent of the choice of kernel.

What is a proper way of those constructions? Exact and approximate number are all fine as long as the data type is consistent in these constructions. 
In the worst case, if this is unresolvable, is there any other free library with this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Circular_arc_point_2` is a point which coordinates are algebraic numbers of degree 2 (only way to represent exactly the intersection of 2 circles). You can convert the point into regular floating point coordinate `Point_2` by using for example `Point_2(to_double(cp.x()), to_double(cp.y()))` but then you'll be loosing the exactness.

Comment: In fact that's what I am using. Converting the intersection (with square root) to the exact kernel (rational) is already inexact, continue treating those as exact in subsequent calculations will cause problems. It seems that the exact kernel can't avoid this approximation. Is there any other kernel support algebraic number constructions, or completely using "double" type approximation?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't. Well you could instantiate the circular kernel with floating point number type but you will most probably observe some assertion failures and non robust operations.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it is impossible in CGAL, so I will switch to a CAS or floating point geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The predefined `Exact_circular_kernel_2` only uses rational number as its field type. To cover every constructible point, you should define a circular kernel that uses a `FieldWithSqrt`. With existing types and traits it is simple:

```
using L = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt;
using A = CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_for_circles_2_2<L::FT>;
using K = CGAL::Circular_kernel_2<L, A>;
```

Then you can convert a `Circular_arc_point_2 p` to `Point_2` with the exact coordinates:

```
K::Point_2 q(p.x(), p.y());
```